# How to execute a function with the package I want

Tags: r, package, rstudio, radix

This is a generic question that could be solved (I guess) by several ways (uninstalling the package, or giving priority a specific package) but I don't really know any of them

As I post in the image, RStudio is continuously offering me functions with strange packages, that I have used once or twice, but contain this generic functions. The problem is I've tried unattaching the packages, not loading them but seems it has no effect. Of course, these functions sometimes have different approaches to the code than the base package

Any help would be welcome[image]

Comment: These are just the auto-complete suggestions of RStudio. It will not affect which function R runs. If you do not have `BiocGenerics` loaded (with `library()` or `require()`) it will not use the `do.call()` from that package. However if you want to be explicit you can do `base::do.call()`.

Comment: Do you load an old workspace? You might want to change the RStudio settings to avoid doing that.

Comment: I know these are autosuggestions, but I would like RStudio not suggesting these packages. 
I don't load old workspace, not on purpose at least. I work with my .rmd files depending on the project, but I usually don't save the workspace

Comment: Have you checked `sessionInfo()`, what is really loaded? If you don't need them, you may [uninstall packages with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26633042/6574038).

Comment: I haven't done this before. The sessionInfo() yields a lot of information. I will explore the uninstall with dependencies